# Lego MOC joining query

Tags: building, moc, wheel, steering

I have a building query. 
As you see the picture (attached). 
I really don't know how the creator can attach the "3829c01" steering wheel to the "4070". 
I try so many rod like parts can't get through the hole of "3829c01"
Hope anyone can help.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: There might well be a "legitimate" way to achieve this build, but we have to be open to the possibility that the builder is "cheating". Many MOCers are happy to use "non-purist" techniques that wouldn't be acceptable in official LEGO models. For some, that includes modifying parts or using non-LEGO components. It is possible that the designer of this particular construction has used unorthodox methods. Do you have any other examples of work by the same builder? If s/he is a serial part-modifier then I wouldn't be surprised if that is what is going on here.

Comment: IE, where do these pictures come from?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to find a few elements that are able to make this connection possible. I'm guessing the designer used some type of bar-sized element which is made from a different material that is able to compress slightly more than regular ABS. For example, the softer plastic used on some minifig weapons seems to work nicely:

[image: Mace and steering wheel]

Another option could be [flexible Technic tubing](http://peeron.com/inv/parts/75). I was able to make this work, but it feels like a very tight fit. This tubing could also be cut to length under some definition of LEGO purism.

[image: Technic tubing and steering wheel]

Of course, as Kramii pointed out, this could also just use non-standard elements or part modification.

Answer (score 0):

They used a "lightsaber blade", more generally called a [Bar 4L](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=30374) or some other [Bar element](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=46). Bar elements are used extensively in SNOT building since they can pass through both Technic axle holes, Hero Factory double holes, open-hole studs, as well as many other elements like the Erhling/Headlight brick with the standard bar sized hole. The standard "clip" type elements also use the same diameter and so can also be added to these combinations.

Comment: Bar elements don't seem to fit through the hole in 3829c01 as noted in the question. You might be thinking of 30663. That part is commonly attached using bar elements.

Comment: Yup. "Bar 4L" can't get through "3829c01" steering wheel. I tried. Thanks for helping anyway :)

Comment: I'm fairly confident he forced the wheel to make it fit